# Regular Expression to match dot separated list allowing one or more word

Tags: c#, regex

I need an regex that allows an input string with one or more words, but the list must be separated with only a dot. For example:

```
test = OK
test.test = OK
test.test.1 = OK

test@test = NO
test_test = NO
test-test1 = NO
test. = NO
```

My regex works, but accepts also other symbols, such as `-`

```
^[a-z0-9*.\-_\.:]+$
```

Comment: Why not just remove the other symbols from your regex? i.e. `^[a-z0-9.]+$`. If you want to ensure that it doesn't begin or end with a dot, use `^[a-z0-9]+(?:\.[a-z0-9]+)*$`

Comment: Why `test` is ok and `testtest1` is not?

Comment: @John please post your answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to ensure that it doesn't begin or end with a dot, use `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$`

Explanation:

- `^` - Match beginning of input
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - Match alphanumeric sequence
- `(?:` - Beginning of a non-capturing group

  - `\.` - Match a single `.`
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - Match a alphanumeric sequence
- `)` - Close the group
- `*` - Repeat previous group any number of times
- `$` - Match end of input

You can also replace `[a-zA-Z0-9]` with `[^\W_]`, as this will match any character that's not non-word and also not underscore. Basically `\w` minus the `_` character.

Answer (score 1):

Try `^[A-Za-z0-9]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$`

- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` match a word (letters or numbers)
- `(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*` - match any following words separated by a dot

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ypRFem/1/)